# Draw a polygon in OpenGL GLUT with mouse

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glut, opengl-compat

i want to draw a polygon in openGL Glut with mouse interaction, every left click that will be made will be a vertex and a line will be drawn between every vertex. when the right mouse will be clicked the polygon will close drawing a line from the last to the first vertex. I have come up with this but it doesnt seem to work.

```
void draw_polygon(int button, int state, int x, int y) {

    bool right_pushed = 0;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);

    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        p1.x = x;
        p1.y = 480 - y;

        //if right is clicked draw a line to here
        first.x = x;
        first.y = 480 - y;
    }

    while (right_pushed == false) {

        if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
            p2.x = x;
            p2.y = 480 - y;
        }

        GLfloat dx = p2.x - p1.x;
        GLfloat dy = p2.y - p1.y;

        GLfloat x1 = p1.x;
        GLfloat y1 = p1.y;

        GLfloat step = 0;

        if (abs(dx) > abs(dy)) {
            step = abs(dx);
        }
        else {
            step = abs(dy);
        }

        GLfloat xInc = dx / step;
        GLfloat yInc = dy / step;


        for (float i = 1; i <= step; i++) {
            glVertex2i(x1, y1);
            x1 += xInc;
            y1 += yInc;
        }


        p1.x = p2.x;
        p1.y = 480 - y;

        if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {

            right_pushed = 1;
            p2.x = first.x;
            p2.y = first.y;

            dx = p2.x - p1.x;
            dy = p2.y - p1.y;

            x1 = p1.x;
            y1 = p1.y;

            step = 0;

            if (abs(dx) > abs(dy)) {
                step = abs(dx);
            }
            else {
                step = abs(dy);
            }

            xInc = dx / step;
            yInc = dy / step;


            for (float i = 1; i <= step; i++) {

                glVertex2i(x1, y1);
                x1 += xInc;
                y1 += yInc;

            }

        }
    }

    glEnd();
    glFlush();


}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("windows");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(draw_polygon);//
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

i am also trying to find out how to add a functionallity that when i select from a menu i could go from creating this polygon to editing it in a way that i could select a vertex , move it arround, and the shape changes accordingly.

Comment: You are drawing in your mouse function. Don't do this. Save the polygon in a variable (e.g. a list of points). Then your mouse function can modify this list and your display function can render it. Modifying the polygon can then be done similarly. Btw, if you just start learning OpenGL, please don't learn the deprecated fixed function pipeline with `glBegin / glEnd / glVertex ...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to separate the mouse events and the drawing function.

In the mouse event you should just collect the inputs. I Suggest to use a [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) for this. The following function adds a point to the `std::vector` if the left mouse button is pressed. If the right button is pressed the polygon is marked closed. If the left button is pressed again, the polygon is cleared and the process restarts.

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int vp_width = 640;
int vp_height = 480;

std::array<int, 2> currentPt;
std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> pts;
bool closed = false;

void draw_polygon(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    currentPt = std::array<int, 2>{x, vp_height-y}; 

    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        if ( closed )
            pts.clear(); // restart if last action was close
        closed = false;
        pts.push_back( currentPt );
    }
    if ( button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN )
        closed = true;
}
```

In a mouse move event function you can track the current mouse position:

```
void mouse_move(int x, int y)
{
    currentPt = std::array<int, 2>{x, vp_height-y};
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

In your main loop you can continuously draw the lines between the current points. The fllowing function draw lines betwwen a list of points. If the "cloesd" flag is set, then the polygon is closed. Else a line from the last point in the list to the current mouse position is drawn.

```
void display(void)
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if ( !pts.empty() )
    {
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for ( auto &pt : pts )
            glVertex2f( (float)pt[0], (float)pt[1] );
        auto &endPt = closed ? pts.front() : currentPt;
        glVertex2f( (float)endPt[0], (float)endPt[1] );
        glEnd();
    }

    //glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

```
int main()
{
    ..... 
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc (mouse_move);
    glutMouseFunc(draw_polygon);

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glOrtho(0.0f, (float)vp_width, 0.0f, (float)vp_height, -1.0, 1.0);
    .....
}
```

Preview:

[image: preview]

Comment: That's a lot more clear, i cant find tutorials and examples on these things. in the drawing polygon function im trying to let more shapes in the canvas so i could merge them in a union im removing the pts.clear() function and adding recursively the drawing. is this a good idea?