# Not getting an output for OpenGL to print line using mouse click

Tags: c, opengl, mouse, glut, mouseclick-event

My aim is to draw a line using mouse click. When you click the first click it reads the coordinates then when for the nest click it will draw the line using GL_LINES with first and second points.

```
int first, x1, yi, x2, yj, ww = 600, wh = 400;
void drawl()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  
    glLineWidth(5.00);
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2i(x1,yi);
        glVertex2i(x2,yj);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void Display()
{
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);  
    glColor3f(0.7, 0.4, 0.0);  
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  
    glFlush();  
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        if(first == 0)
        {       
            first++;
            x1 = x;
            yi = wh - y;
        }
        else
        {
            x2 = x;
            yj = wh - y;
            drawl();
            printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n",x1,yi,x2,yj);
            first--;
        }   

    }
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    first = 0;
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutCreateWindow("Mouse");
    gluOrtho2D(0,800,0,500);
    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Output I got is given below.  It is not drawing the line. Should I include myinit() function and why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this answer I ported the answer which I had given to the question [Draw a polygon in OpenGL GLUT with mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47123256/draw-a-polygon-in-opengl-glut-with-mouse/47124170#47124170) from C++ to C.

You have to separate the mouse events and the drawing function.

In the mouse (`void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)`) event you should just collect the inputs.

- If the left mouse button is pressed, the following function adds a the X coordinate of the mouse position to the array `ptListX` and the Y-coordinate to the array `ptListY`.
- If the right button is pressed the polygon is marked closed. If the left button is pressed again, the polygon is cleared and the process restarts.

```
int wndSizwX = 800, wndSizeY = 500; // size of the window
int mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;         // current mouse position

#define MAX_PTS 100
int ptListX[MAX_PTS]; // X coordinate ot the input points 
int ptListY[MAX_PTS]; // Y coordinate of the input points
int noOfPts = 0;      // number of input points
int closed = 0;       // marke polygon "closed"

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    mouseX = x;
    mouseY = y;

    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        if (closed || noOfPts >= MAX_PTS - 1)
            noOfPts = 0; // restart the polygon
        closed = 0;
        ptListX[noOfPts] = mouseX; 
        ptListY[noOfPts] = mouseY;
        noOfPts ++;
    }
    if ( button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN )
        closed = 1;
}
```

In a mouse move event function the current mouse position can be tracked:

```
void mouse_move(int x, int y)
{
    mouseX = x;
    mouseY = y;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

In the main loop (`Display` function), the current list of points is connected to lines and continuously drawn. If the `cloesd` flag is set, then the polygon is closed. Else a line from the last point in the list to the current mouse position is drawn.

```
void Display()
{
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);  
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  

    if (noOfPts)
    {
        glLineWidth(5.0);
        glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for (int i=0; i<noOfPts; ++i )
            glVertex2f( (float)ptListX[i], (float)ptListY[i] );
        if ( closed )
            glVertex2f( (float)ptListX[0], (float)ptListY[0] );
        else
            glVertex2f( (float)mouseX, (float)mouseY );
        glEnd();
    }

    glFlush();  
}
```

The registration of the mouse move event has to be add to the main program by `glutPassiveMotionFunc`.
Further the Y-Axis of the orthographic projection has to be flipped, to match the view space to the mouse coordinates:

```
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(wndSizwX,wndSizeY);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutCreateWindow("Mouse");

    gluOrtho2D(0, wndSizwX, wndSizeY, 0); // flip Y 

    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouse_move);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

See the preview:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all You do not actually draw anything - function `drawl` is called only when You click every second time. To draw a line (or anything) one need to call a drawing routine every frame, like the `Display` function is called.

Second thing is that position given in `mouse` callback function is not suitable for defining a point in 3D. One have to translate them onto proper coordinates (that is ranging from -1 to 1 usually) to be able to use them as drawing data. Otherwise GL will try to draw some lines out of view, which means nothing will be drawn.

I would reorganize the application structure a bit - when You get `mouse` call instead of calling `drawl` every other call to it, store the properly translated positions the `mouse` function gives You in some global variable and do the drawing in `Display` routine. Also `gluOrtho2D` should usually be called every frame as well. In Your call to it You have the parameters wrong - see the [reference page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml) for details.